# Connection reset error on multiple file upload

Tags: php, apache, file, upload, cpanel

I have problem in multiple file upload in php. I have set php.ini setting in .htaccess file

```
php upload_max_filesize 1024M
php post_max_size 1024M
php max_execution_time 120
php max_input_time 120
php max_file_uploads 40
```

So when I upload images approx 40M size then server respond with status failed or connection reset instead of it upload images within 1 min time .If I upload little less than 40M then its working fine.Is there any other setting I have to do. How I can fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you're running against the clock or have conflicting settings, but it's hard to tell with the amount of information you provided.

Even though you set up your PHP instance to accept uploads of up to 1024M (are you sure you need this, by the way?) there's a lot more you need to consider:

```
php max_execution_time 120
php max_input_time 120
```

The above means that whatever happens, your PHP instances will be stopped after 120 seconds. It may be that you are able to upload almost 40M in under 120 seconds.

Now, even if you had a connection speed that allows to upload more than 40M in less than 120 seconds, there's more settings thay may be conflicting, as the above ones only apply to the PHP process.

Check your Apache settings (I assume you use Apache given the tag on your question) and look for Apache's directives regarding execution times and upload limits. Even if PHP was configured to allow 1 Terabyte per file and 24 hours per process, if Apache has more restrictive limits, Apache will be constraining your upload sizes and running times.

Comment: What and where I have to check in apache.

Comment: httpd.conf would be a good place to start. I'm sorry I cannot provide more detail as I'm less familiar with Apache than Nginx. Perhaps you may find more info a ServerFault